# datalist selectedindexchanged not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

Page Load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

       tb.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        tb.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
        tb.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));
        tb.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(int));

        newtb.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        newtb.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
        newtb.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));
        newtb.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(int));

        path = objGetBaseCase.GetAllImagesfromGroup(CaseId);
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
        {
            ArrayList alst = path[i];
            tb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(alst[0]), alst[1].ToString(), alst[2].ToString(), i);

        }
        msgError.Text = "";

        dlstImage.DataSource = tb;
        DataBind();
        List<ArrayList> t = new List<ArrayList>();
        if (newpath.Count > 0)
        {
            t = newpath;
            newpath = t;
            for (int i = 0; i < newpath.Count; i++)
            {
                ArrayList alst = newpath[i];
                newtb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(alst[0]), alst[1].ToString(), alst[2].ToString(), i);

            }
            ViewState["tempimage"] = newpath;
            dlstSelectedImages.DataSource = newtb;
            DataBind();
        }

}
```

Datalist SelectedIndexChanged:

```
  protected void dlstSelectedImages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    indexId = Convert.ToInt32(dlstSelectedImages.DataKeys[dlstSelectedImages.SelectedIndex]);
  }
```

DataList:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlstSelectedImages" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                RepeatColumns="5" CellSpacing="8" DataKeyField="Id"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlstSelectedImages_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="Image"  runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Controls/ShowImage.ashx?FileName=" +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'
                                        CommandName="Select" OnCommand="ImageSelect_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() +";"+Eval("FilePath")+";"+Eval("Index")+";"+Eval("FileName") %>' /><br />
                   <asp:Label ID="nlbl" runat="server" Text="Figure"></asp:Label><%# dlstSelectedImages.Items.Count + 1%>
          </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

Itried with: `View State="Enable"`, `AutoEventWireup="true"`,

```
autopostback="true"
```

It was working well when i was binding the datalist inside this !IsPostBack but now I don't want to bind my datalist inside the !IsPostBack and I don't want to use ItemCommand as well

But its not working, someone help me...

Comment: Why not bind within `if(!IsPostBack)` ? Do it and see the result

Comment: @v4vendetta: when i am binding if(!IsPostBack) its working but i am loosing the images in datalist, its not showing the images, so i dn't want to use if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: @v4vendetta: I tried but its not working

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the not working part ? does it postback or the code is not reached or you have exception ..whatttt

Comment: I am binding 2 datalist at the same time, when i am keeping all code in side the If(!IsPostBack) then its working fine but all the items of datalist1 is getting doubled, I tried with keeping my datalist for which i am using selectedindex then also its not working

Comment: when i am doing is, binding all the item in datalist1 and moving few selected items in datalist2 with the help of on btnmove down, after that i'm swapping the items, at the item of swapping i need selected indexId but the event is not firing

Comment: When i'm selecting the image that breakpoint is not going inside the IsPostback, condition is shoing true

Comment: my page load is calling 2 times, and in 2nd time datasource is showing null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the `SelectedIndex` Change event fires, the `Page_Load` event is called before the `selectedIndex` Change event. In your page_load event, your `DataList` binded again and hence your SelectedIndex event was lost. You have to put your DataList binding code under `!IsPostBack` e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
   newtb.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
   newtb.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
   newtb.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));
   newtb.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(int));

   List<ArrayList> t = new List<ArrayList>();
    if (newpath.Count > 0)
    {
        t = newpath;
        newpath = t;
        for (int i = 0; i < newpath.Count; i++)
        {
            ArrayList alst = newpath[i];
            newtb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(alst[0]), alst[1].ToString(), alst[2].ToString(), i);

        }
        ViewState["tempimage"] = newpath;
        dlstSelectedImages.DataSource = newtb;
        DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that also, actually i am binding 2 datalist at the same time, i keep this datalist bind inside the If(!IsPostPack) then also its not working.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put in the item template a button or a hyperlink.
[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75670ez0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)